# Kafka producer and consumer delay

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, lag

My kafka producer will push 3 messages with in a SECOND, My consumer will consume and data processing time is 3 SECONDS for each message.

So in 1 MINUTE producer will produce 180 messages, but my consumer will consume only 20 messages in 1 MINUTE. but i want to consume all messages with in 1 MINUTE

Can anyone give me the suggestion to resolve it, instead of increasing instances

Answer (score 0):

It's all depends on your consumer logic. How you process the data from start till the end. Kafka consume message as sequences based on offset.

If your consumer logic is ok with parallel processing, I suggest you to add more partition in your Kafka server. Then you can add multiple consumer on it.

I think it's a good for read about Kafka and multiple partition https://medium.com/@jhansireddy007/how-to-parallelise-kafka-consumers-59c8b0bbc37a

Answer (score 0):

1. Add more partitions
2. Increase your consumer concurrency, this will add more consumer threading in your single instance (process)
3. Speed up your consumer logic as far as possible, it depends.